# How to get all the objects from a json array in postgres but selecting just certain properties?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in a table, and this colum (named services) contains an array of objects like this:

`[{"id": "1", "service_id": "4100002"}, {"id": "2", "service_id": "4100003"}, {"id": "3", "service_id": "410004"}]`

If this same table contains two more columns; id and name. How can i make a query so that the result turns out like this:

| id | name | services |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | alpha | 4100002, 4100003, 410003 |
| 23 | betha | 4100001, 4100005 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a subquery over an [expansion of the array into a set of rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT service_id
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(services) AS s(service_id int)
  ) AS services
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the array and extract the field you want, then agg it back up:

```
select
  id,
  name,
  string_agg(service, ', ') as services
from (
  select id,
  name,
  json_array_elements(named_service)->>'service_id' as service
  from mytable)
group by 1, 2
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8iN4Cv3j).